# suggest the architecture for reporting application with custom templates

Tags: rest, architecture, reporting

Let me put down my requirements, we are designing a solution to satisfy the very dynamic reporting needs. The data for those are generated in sqlite databases for now(they caled it the cubes) so there are lots of cubes on the server machines. The charts which are created on those cubes are developed on telerik reporting engine. They are set of dlls which access the cube data and prepare the chart for UI. The thing that stays the same is the schema. every type of cube has certain schema and sticks with it.

There are new charts after every now and then. I don't wanna mmake it part of new framework to include new chart or chart templates every other day. So i was planning to host it in separate service and call the service to get the data from the framework and process it to create the chart.

Now the issue is the size of the data to be transfered through the wire, which can be of huge size before any business logic applied to it for charting.

So what can be the suggestion to make it more "modular", scalable but somehow make it workable as well. I mean is this even a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are planning to read the database "out from under" another system to bypass the way it works.  This tends to indicate a bad idea but sometimes that's necessary.

If you must read large amounts of data "over the wire" and then process it sounds like you want some type of "sync" process that extracts the data and processes it, separately from the reporting requirements.  Your reports can then work with only the processed data (which means they will perform well) and the sync process can take as long as it needs to extract the data and process it ready for reports.  This is likely to need another database/storage area specifically for the new reports you are creating.

It would be better to continue working with the system the way it was intended if you can.  That means new reports and data "cubes" etc will be built in that system.  If you are going to be building new reports every other day, what do you gain by the solution you are considering vs the solution that is already operating?

Comment: sorry couldn't reply, got busy in travelling. The thing is now they want some ready to use, sort of standard reports. The frequency will be less. Y going for new solution because, the earlier solution is developed in silverlight, now they want it to available for customer and not just internal use and secondly also for tablets.

Comment: I don't know if it helps or not, but if you have to build something new, you could look at Docmosis Cloud Services.  It lets you use templates and can be reached by any platform including the tablets you mentioned.  Good luck.